# Does the javascript engine create a block scope even before it knows if it contains any lexical declarations?

Tags: javascript

It is clear that only `let` and `const` are block scoped, but in the spec it seems that anytime a block is evaluated in [BlockEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation) a new block scope is created with `BlockDeclarationInstantiation`.

> 1. Let oldEnv be the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. Let blockEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv).
> 3. **Perform BlockDeclarationInstantiation(StatementList, blockEnv).**
> 4. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to blockEnv.
> 5. Let blockValue be Completion(Evaluation of StatementList).
> 6. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to oldEnv.
> 7. Return ? blockValue.

In [BlockDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation) it states:

> 1. Let declarations be the **LexicallyScopedDeclarations** of code.

In this code when evaluation of the block begins, according to `step 2`, a block scope is created, but **am I correct in assuming that during the evaluation of the block, a new block scope is created, no `var` variables are registered for the environment record and the scope is thrown out, or since the AST is created in the compilation phase, during execution does the js engine already know ahead of time not to waste time creating a block since the AST shows it contains only a var declaration?**

I would expect that there is first a check to see if there are any *LexicallyScopedDeclarations* before the AO *NewDeclarativeEnvironment* is ran at all.

```js
function foo() {
  if (true) {
    var x = 1
  }
}
```

In the [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) it generates the following json showing a block statement is created with a variable statement within it. It seems during evaluation stage of the js engine, it creates this block scope and realizes there is a `var` declaration and does not register it to that scope.

```json
{
  "type": "Program",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 50,
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "FunctionDeclaration",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 50,
      "id": {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "start": 9,
        "end": 12,
        "name": "foo"
      },
      "expression": false,
      "generator": false,
      "async": false,
      "params": [],
      "body": {
        "type": "BlockStatement",
        "start": 15,
        "end": 50,
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "IfStatement",
            "start": 19,
            "end": 48,
            "test": {
              "type": "Literal",
              "start": 23,
              "end": 27,
              "value": true,
              "raw": "true"
            },
            "consequent": {
              "type": "BlockStatement",
              "start": 29,
              "end": 48,
              "body": [
                {
                  "type": "VariableDeclaration",
                  "start": 35,
                  "end": 44,
                  "declarations": [
                    {
                      "type": "VariableDeclarator",
                      "start": 39,
                      "end": 44,
                      "id": {
                        "type": "Identifier",
                        "start": 39,
                        "end": 40,
                        "name": "x"
                      },
                      "init": {
                        "type": "Literal",
                        "start": 43,
                        "end": 44,
                        "value": 1,
                        "raw": "1"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "kind": "var"
                }
              ]
            },
            "alternate": null
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "module"
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `var` declarations have any influence in scoping. You can place them anywhere, but the runtime will just assume they are at the beginning of the block (I think it's called var hoisting).

Comment: That wasn't the question, during the parsing phase of compilation, it will show that the block statement contains a variable declaration, my question is since `BlockEvaluation` is a runtime evaluation, it states that a new declarative environment (block scope) is created, but obviously `var` won't be registered to that scope since var is not block scoped. I am wondering if the engine even creates the scope at all or looks at the ast and realizes it can skip creating a block scope since var wont be registered to it in this case

Comment: I would guess that your intuition is correct, in that one would assume that a V8 internals developer would take absolutely any opportunity to not do something when it's clear that it's not necessary. That is, however, just a guess, and an implementation detail like that might change at any time. The key is that if it doesn't affect language semantics, internal optimizations might change any such detail.

Comment: You talk about "the" javascript engine which in itself is wrong. There are lots of javascript engines out there (V8, SpiderMonkey and JavaScriptCore being the ones used in most browsers today but there are others as well). Your question is about what could possibly be an optimization but nothing that really has a canonical for every engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec details only the behaviour of a javascript program, not the specific steps an engine will execute (or optimise away) when running a script. Whether empty unnecessary scopes will be created and used, created and immediately thrown away, or not created at all, is an implementation detail and will not affect the observable behaviour. At best, your debugger might be able to give you a glimpse at it.

Comment: Ok thank you, I did use the debugger and I understand what you mean, the reason I was confused is because the spec indeed details the behavior of a program and it states rather explicitly that when a block is evaluated a new declarative environment record is indeed created. I would assume a js engine implementation would perhaps do this and then mark the empty scope for garbage collection but it seems pointless to create an empty scope.

Comment: No. The engine also won't call `getLexicallyScopedDeclarations` every time it enters a block, but rather it will have statically compiled that once. Similarly, environment records form a linked list in the spec, and identifier resolution needs to traverse that list every time a variable is evaluated, but no engine does that - it's statically resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It will likely depend on each engine. Useless work that has no effect on the execution of the code is typically optimised away, or even not generated in the first place. For example, though `+` has a very specific definition in the spec, I would expect `console.log(2+4)` to be compiled into the same code as `console.log(6)`, though if the engine was executing the spec literally, it should not do that.

[Here](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-lexical-environment-and-environment-record-specification-types) it specifically says:

> The Environment Record type is used to explain the behaviour of name resolution in nested functions and blocks.

These types and the behaviour that the specification expects from them is the simplest way to explain how JavaScript code should behave; but it is not there to suggest how an engine should work internally. Any of these explanations can and will be ignored if it results in a better execution, while preserving the outwardly visible semantics of the engine viewed as a black box.